# Logical Operators in Javascript when Comparing Strings to Strings from Input

Tags: javascript, string, validation, if-statement, input

I would like to validate user answers given in an input field to existing values. I don't know if I am going the right way about it or not, but I would like to keep the code as simple as possible.

The idea is to check the user input either matches the first or the second world, if yes, the text turns "green" the inputted word doesn't mach the any of the worlds it turns "red" and bold. So far all it does is to turn any text inputted bold and red, but only(!) if I remove the else statement....

Any help is appreciated!

```
<div id="quiz">
<p id="firstAnswer" value="Tiistai">Tiistai</p>
<p id="secondAnswer" value="Kedd">Kedd</p>
<input type="text" name="userText" id="userAnswer" value="" placeholder="...">
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" name="Busca" id="Busca" value="Check" onClick="ver()"; />
</div>

<script>

    var answer1 = document.getElementById('firstAnswer');
    var answer2 = document.getElementById('secondAnswer');
    var answer3 = document.getElementById('userAnswer');

    function ver(){ 
        if (answer1 != answer3 || answer2 != answer3){
            var element=document.getElementById("userAnswer");
            document.getElementById("userAnswer").style.fontWeight="bold";
            document.getElementById("userAnswer").style.color='red';
            };
        else {
            document.getElementById("userAnswer").style.fontWeight="bold";
            document.getElementById("userAnswer").style.color='green';
            };
        };

</script>
```

Comment: `answer1`, `answer2`, and `answer3` refer to the DOM elements (that's what `document.getElementById` returns). You need to get their values by using `.value`. Then you are comparing the values that were inputted

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, adding .value doesn't help, the result is the same.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully look at the HTML. Why are you setting `value` on the `<p>` elements? They don't have a `value` attribute

Comment: You have a misplaced `;` after the `if () {}`. This makes the `if-else` statement invalid. You also have them after the `else {}` and the `function ver(){}`, but those are harmless.

Comment: Thank! Corrected them, but still it just turns text to red :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things wrong here. First, here's how I'd set it up:

HTML -

```
<div id="quiz">
    <p id="firstAnswer" data-value="Tiistai">Tiistai</p>
    <p id="secondAnswer" data-value="Kedd">Kedd</p>
    <input type="text" name="userText" id="userAnswer" value="" placeholder="..." />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="button" name="Busca" id="Busca" value="Check" onClick="ver()" />
</div>
```

JS -

```
var answer1Element = document.getElementById('firstAnswer'),
    answer2Element = document.getElementById('secondAnswer'),
    userAnswerElement = document.getElementById("userAnswer");

function ver() {
    var answer1, answer2, userAnswer;
    answer1 = answer1Element.getAttribute("data-value");
    answer2 = answer2Element.getAttribute("data-value");
    userAnswer = userAnswerElement.value;
    if (answer1 !== userAnswer && answer2 !== userAnswer) {
        userAnswerElement.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        userAnswerElement.style.color = 'red';
    } else {
        userAnswerElement.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        userAnswerElement.style.color = 'green';
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/RS5US/

Before a recent edit to the question, an original problem was that the values compared in the `if` statement were `Element`s, and would always be `!==`. Immediately changing the variables to point to their `.value`s doesn't solve it, for the following reason.

`<p>` elements don't have a `value` attribute, so you should use `data-value` in the HTML and get the attribute with `.getAttribute()`. Sure, you can ignore the `value`/`data-value` attributes and use `innerHTML`/`innerText`/`textContent`, but I like to separate these things when you may want to format what it looks like differently than the actual value. `data-value` should contain the raw value you want to compare/accept.

As a bonus, instead of using `getAttribute()`, you could learn about `dataset`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset

Also, your `if` statement had a `;` at the end of it, which messed up the `else`.

Also, your `if` statement logic was a little weird - it would've always evaluated to `true` because the user's answer would always satisfy one of the conditions (if not both).

As a suggestion - I'd toggle a specific `class` instead of setting `.style` properties of a DOM element. It just keeps it easier to track.

And as a bonus for this, you could learn about `classList`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList

Comment: I think you just might use `.textContent` instead of any attributes :-)

Comment: @Bergi I was literally updating (and just finished) my answer about that. Definitely an option, but if there's formatting/other stuff you want to display, it's "safer" with an attribute, I'd say. Of course, in this code/example, the values are exactly the same, but in a different situation maybe they won't be

Comment: @Ian I agree it's safer to rely on data attributes and that's what I would do (actually I would have a model in memory rather than querying the DOM), however `textContent` will just grab the text content so formatting shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @plalx As I've said, in case there's more information, such as a hint inside of parentheses, then it would grab too much. You're right about formatting, but extra whitespace **could** be a problem. Obviously you could trim, but still

Answer (score -2):

It should be:

```
if (answer1 != answer3 && answer2 != answer3){
                       ^^
```

Didn't you ever learn [deMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)?

Or just reverse your `if` to simplify it:

```
if (answer1 == answer3 || answer2 == answer3) {
    document.getElementById("userAnswer").style.fontWeight="bold";
    document.getElementById("userAnswer").style.color='green';
} else {
    document.getElementById("userAnswer").style.fontWeight="bold";
    document.getElementById("userAnswer").style.color='red';
}
```

You're also not setting the `answerX` variables correctly. It should be:

```
var answer1 = document.getElementById("firstAnswer").innerHTML;
var answer2 = document.getElementById("secondAnswer").innerHTML;

function ver() {
    var answer3 = document.getElementById("userAnswer").value;
    if (answer1 == answer3 || answer2 == answer3) {
        document.getElementById("userAnswer").style.fontWeight="bold";
        document.getElementById("userAnswer").style.color='green';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("userAnswer").style.fontWeight="bold";
        document.getElementById("userAnswer").style.color='red';
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/XG8d3/)

Comment: No luck, but at least now it turns all text to red ;)

Comment: Added more fixes, and a jsfiddle demo